# Finding auto_increment value for multiple insert queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, auto-increment

I have a form to enter a student's name and his marks.

---

I have two tables :

**student**

```
student_id | student_name
         1 | John
         2 | Doe
```

**marks**

```
student_id | mark
         1 | 80
         2 | 90
```

---

The *Student Name* field has an autocomplete function which checks the **student** table if the student already exists.

Now, if I type **J** in the *Student Name* field in the form, it shows John. If I click John, and then enter a mark(say 50) in the *Mark* field and submit the form, the **student** table remain untouched, while the **marks** table gets inserted with a new row (1 | 50), where 1 is the *student_id* of the selected student (In this case, id of John).

Now, if I type a new name (say, Rae) in the *Student Name* field, and some mark(say 75) in the *Mark* field, both tables should get inserted with a new row on form submit. i.e., **student** table should now have a new row (3 | Rae) and **marks** table should have a new row (3 | 75)

MY PROBLEM IS, since *student_id* is an auto_incremented value from **student**, the *student_id* field in the **marks** table get a value 0 while entering a new student (In this case, Rae), which insert the row as (0 | 75) instead of my requirement (3 | 75).

As far as I know, mysqli_insert_id() can be used here, but I'm using three insert statements in a go. The above mentioned two insert queries are second and third. The auto_increment value from the first insert is being used for some other purpose using the mysqli_insert_id() command.

Comment: if you cannot use `last_insert_id`, just query the element by name and get the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` within your query to get the new ID. For example:

```
INSERT INTO student (student_name) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO marks (student_id, mark) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 74);
```